# Why am I getting chinese characters as output only?

Tags: visual-c++

I have a program running ,which attaches to Notepad and can succesfully read the first 20 characters written in Notepad, but if I am trying to write some bytes back to Notepad.exe it gives me a lot chinese resembling characters.
Perhaps a unicode issue ?
But I created a byte array !?

Already tried to read and write the value back as char array and as string..

```
BYTE text[20];
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    ReadProcessMemory(han, (void*)start2, &text[i], sizeof(QWORD), 0);
    start2 += 2;
}
printf("%s\n", text);
```

Expected result : change string of notepad.exe.
Actual result : string is shown in letters I do not understand.

Comment: My guess: you are building a Unicode build, so `%s` format specifier expects a `wchar_t*` pointer, but you are passing `char*`. Then every two bytes are interpreted as one Unicode character. Try `%hs`

Comment: well I guess the real problem lies here :

Comment: ```for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
 WriteProcessMemory(han, (void*)start2, &newtext[i], sizeof(QWORD), 0);
 printf("%s", newtext[i]);
 start2 += 2;
 }```

Comment: There's a buffer overrun in your `ReadProcessMemory` call. You read 8 bytes at a time, but once `i > 12`, you have fewer than 8 bytes in the buffer pointed to by `&text[i]`. Besides, each subsequent read overwrites all but the first byte of previous read.

Comment: thank you, I guess I solved my problem.. It was solved by using wchar_t instead of BYTE array. Now I have here something nice and fancy,just another trick, but thanks again.